# Node.JS undefined is not a function on required module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use a class that I created called user.js.  The code for this user is:

```
function User(){};

User.prototype.addUser = function(){
    //Do stuff
    return 0;
};

module.exports = User;
```

I'm including it in my index.js route file, which looks like this:

```
var config = require('../lib/config');
var db = require('../lib/db');
var User = require('../lib/user');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET create user. */
router.get('/newuser', function(req, res, next) {
    *****var newuser = User.addUser();*****

    res.render('index', {   
                        user: newuser
                    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, when I visit localhost/newuser, I get the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.  This error is being thrown in index.js on the line I marked with 5 asterisks above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining a constructor named `User()` and exporting it.  But, then when you `require('../lib/user')`, you get the constructor function, but you never construct a new object with it so you don't actually have an object of type `User`, you just have the constructor and thus there is no method `addUser()` on the constructor.

Instead of this:

```
var User = require('../lib/user');
```

you can call the constructor function like this:

```
var u = require('../lib/user');
var User = new u();
```

Or, if you never need to make another one, you can do it all in one line:

```
var User = new (require('../lib/user'))();
```

Comment: So is there a way to include both the constructor and other functions as well?  Like, I can call `var newuser = new User();` and also have the function `User.addUser();` seperately?

Comment: @terpak - it depends upon what you're really trying to do.  When you put `addUser` on the prototype, you made it available only on an instance of the `User` object, not on the constructor function.  A constructor function is an object that can have properties also so in your module you could define `User.addUser = function() {}` and this would make a static function on your constructor.  It's static because it is not a method of an instance, but rather just a ultility function that can be called at any time and does not operate on a specific `User` instance.

Comment: @jfriend00 I had to use `var User = new (require('../lib/user'))();`  Note the `( ... )` around the require statement.  Otherwise, User is undefined.  Using node version v4.2.4.  Thank you for your answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to change your User.js class to return something on these lines...

```
function User(){};

User.prototype.addUser = function(){
    //Do stuff
    return 0;
};

module.exports = new User();
```