# NodeJs undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using NodeJs to run this code
this is my custom module

```
call = {};
call.hangup = {
    searching: function(number, mysql, validator){
        this.number = number;
        this.mysql = mysql;
        this.validator = validator;
        var query = "{sql...}";
        try
        {   
            mysql.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {        
            if (err) throw err; 
                if(!validator.isNull(rows))
                {                                       
                    return rows.leadid;                     
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }catch(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    },
    test: function(number, mysql, validator){
        var self = this;
        this.number = number;
        this.mysql = mysql;
        this.validator = validator;
        var result = self.searching(number, mysql, validator);
        console.log(result);
    }
};
module.exports = call;
```

then call test function in my main file

```
call.hangup.test(number, connection, validator);
```

but I'm getting this error code in my console :

```
                var result = self.searching(leadid, mysql, validator);
                                  ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

how can I fix it ?
and why this happen ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622467/node-js-undefined-is-not-a-function-on-required-module This will help!

Comment: @SandeepNayak nope, I try it :(

Comment: It would appear something is changing the context of your object. Either when you require it. Or something before when you call it. `Console.log` `this` inside it to see if the context is what you expect. You can also `bind` it, or use `call` etc to set it but you should find whats changing it. Also why are you aliasing `this` with `self`? There's no need. Also you setting `number` `mysql` and `validator` twice. You should either pass it into `searching` for it to set or set it in `test` and just read them in `searching`.

Comment: Your error is referring to a line of code that isn't present in your question. While it is likely this is because you're executing `test` in such a way that `this` does not point to the correct object, it could be that your error is from a different section of code.

Comment: See also: http://www.unicodegirl.com/this-is-the-calling-object.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this`  reference (which you assigned to `self variable`)points to `test function` and test function does not have a function called `searching`.That is why you got this error. You should call `searching` function in this way `call.hangup.searching`

```
call = {};
call.hangup = {
    searching: function(number, mysql, validator){
        this.number = number;
        this.mysql = mysql;
        this.validator = validator;
        var query = "{sql...}";
        try
        {   
            mysql.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {        
            if (err) throw err; 
                if(!validator.isNull(rows))
                {                                       
                    return rows.leadid;                     
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }catch(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    },

    test: function(number, mysql, validator){

        this.number = number;
        this.mysql = mysql;
        this.validator = validator;
        var result = call.hangup.searching(number, mysql, validator);
        console.log(result);
    }
};
module.exports = call;
```

**EDIT:**
You can also assigne `self` variable to `call.hangup`

```
test: function(number, mysql, validator){
            var self = call.hangup;
            this.number = number;
            this.mysql = mysql;
            this.validator = validator;
            var result = self.searching(number, mysql, validator);
            console.log(result);
        }
```

Comment: How can I included searching function to this scope ?